# RewriteRule Regex 301 redirect not performing any redirect

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to implement a 301 redirect for a site that we've migrated to a new storefront. I want to use regex to do it because there's a huge amount of products that I don't want to have to map one by one. Essentially, the site right now is https://printandmail.byu.edu/simaterials and all of the products on the site append to the URL. The new site I want to redirect all parts of this site to is https://pmstore.byu.edu/DSF/SmartStore.aspx?6xni2of2cF1NZ/ji88abwKk016at/khdaqjyMf5Xsn5GQuQPzO7bC4Ekzl6GiEqF#!/CategoryHome/142. However, when I add the following lines to the htaccess file nothing happens.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(https:\/\/)?printandmail\.byu\.edu\/simaterials\/(.*)$ https://pmstore.byu.edu/DSF/SmartStore.aspx?6xni2of2cF1NZ/ji88abwKk016at/khdaqjyMf5Xsn5GQuQPzO7bC4Ekzl6GiEqF#!/CategoryHome/142 [R=301,L]
```

I've even tried to just hardcode the main page into the first URL to see if any redirect would happen at all and nothing. From everything I've looked it up it seems like my syntax is correct, so I'm really not sure what I'm missing. Anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: Try: `RewriteRule ^simaterials/ /DSF/SmartStore.aspx?6xni2of2cF1NZ/ji88abwKk016at/khdaqjyMf5Xsn5GQuQPzO7bC4Ekzl6GiEqF#!/CategoryHome/142 [R=301,L,NE,NC]`

Comment: _“so I'm really not sure what I'm missing”_ - for starters, the fact that RewriteRule matches against the _path_ component of the URL only.

Comment: Ah I get what you mean. I didn't realize RewriteRule only matched the path. So how am I supposed to redirect to a new domain then? Is RewriteRule not the right command to be using?

Comment: Okay I understand now. you just have to specify the new domain on the second one and not on the first. I didn't realized that RewriteRule only looked at the path, thanks for the help!